# Using Rand in Testing in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to test my "Roll Dice" function, that then produces the current running score of the game.

The signature is:

```
func rollDice(randFunc: ((ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int)? = Int.random) -> (dice1: Int, dice2: Int, losePointsTurn: Bool, losePointsGame: Bool)
```

as I want to swap out the random function so I can test this, and the random function is called through:

```
dice1 = randFunc!(0...5)
dice2 = randFunc!(0...5)
```

I created an extension for a non-random function in my test target

```
extension ClosedRange {
    func noRand(_ : Bool) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

but when I try to use this in my test:

```
gm.rollDice(randFunc: ClosedRange<Int>.noRand)
```

I have the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(ClosedRange) -> (Bool) -> Int' to
>   expected argument type '((ClosedRange) -> Int)?'

So how can I write a non-random random function to swap into this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sample code the `noRand` should be a function that accepts a `ClosedRange` and returns `Int`.

There is no reason to make it an extension to `ClosedRange`. Additionally, you are free to peek the signature of the `Int.random` static method and essentially copy-and-paste.

The signature of it is `(ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int`, noted as `random(in:)`. Your `noRand` function must have the same signature.

Thus, this leaves us with

```swift
func noRand(in range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

Note that it needs not to be put as an extension to `ClosedRange`. And considering the fact that you would use it in testing only, you might as well declare in scope level.

Comment: How can I make this an inline function?         gm.rollDice { ((ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int)? in
            return 0
        }

Comment: I think you can even leave out the type information and the return keyword like so: `{_ in 0}`

Comment: @stevenpcurtis Exactly, it's enough to `{ _ in 0 }`

Comment: well that was easy